# como formatar o option do select ao passar o mouse em cima

Tags: html, css, select, option

Como faço com css para deixar o opção selecionada com uma determinada cor ao passar o mouse por cima??

```
<select>
  <option>werwe</option>  <-- quero deixar esse cara em laranja ao selecionar
</select>
```

tem como??
obrigado a todos!!
Grande abraço!!
Horácio

Comment: Não ficou muito claro, vc quer trocar a cor depois que seleciona, tipo cada option de uma cor depois de selecionado, ou vc quer trocar a cor só no hover, pouco importanto o option que está selecionado?

Comment: só no hover...ele está azul , quero deixar o hover no option laranja